# The view above recyclerview is skipped

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have CardView above RecycleView, but when Page is loaded RecyclerView is  on the top and CardView is skipped. Why can this happen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/homeProgress"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorText"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeMainLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/firstPlace"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorCardView"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/firstPlaceName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="30sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/firstPlaceCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/firstPlaceImage"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/artistsWithImagesRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstPlace"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you also add the java code for your activity

Comment: Use One Constraint layout as parent and then define all childs layout with proper constraint. Also, use matchConstraint for recyclerview height and constraint it to bottom of parent.

Answer (score 1):

align your recyler view to top to bottom of card view

Answer (score 0):

You have set the ConstraintLayout with id homeMainLayout to be "gone". Remove the attribute  android:visibility="gone" from it and the card view will be shown as you expect.

Comment: RecyclerView is in this ConstraintLayout too, I change visibility in program.

Answer (score 0):

Add weight to cardview and recyclerview or change constraint layout to relative layout, remove below lines in recyclerview

`app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent`